# Finding documentation for subclassing UIKit Elements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

It seems that a lot of customization in iOS requires that one override the default behavior of elements in UIKit by either using categories or subclassing.

How does one view the inner workings of classes such as UIButton and UIWebView without documentation? For .NET, there's Reflector. Does anything like that exist for Cocoa?

Answer (score 1):

There is pretty good documentation.  For example, [UIView programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html), [UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) and [UIWebKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Search for the apple programming guides and * class reference.  I would recommend reading all the programming guides, using the class reference docs and above all, write sample code using the controls to understand exactly how they behave.

.net, is compiled to IL and JITted to native at runtime.  So, it's fairly easy for something like reflector or ILSpy to not only be able to reflect over the metadata at runtime but also reverse engineer the code.

Objective-c and C code is compiled into native code so you won't get it reverse engineered into readable code like those.  The only thing I've seen is otx:  http://davegoodell.blogspot.com/2009/05/otx-objective-c-disassembly.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what bryanmac said, you can also dump the view hierarchy recursively by sending any `UIView` instance a `recursiveDescription` message.  For more details, see [Technical Note TN2239: iOS Debugging Magic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html).

**Edit:** But please be aware that modifying the view hierarchy of most Apple-supplied `UIView` subclasses is forbidden, and iOS 5 has introduced other ways of customising the look and behaviour of them.